# How to create user access using shortcut bar and xplistbar

Tags: powerbuilder, user-accounts, datawindow

Good afternoon Everyone,
Please me to ask,
How to create user access when IM using shortcut bar,and inside shortcut bar i use xplistbar, for example, shortcut bar is for departemen name, and in xplistbar is for master, transaction,report, please help,Thank You in advance

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Do you have a screenshot or code to show as an example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the screen shoot Mr Matt Ballent,i purpose this window as a main window. for example, for user Mr A, he is only can open module Production and Inventory, and only for some transaction or report, and it takes from DW menu, i don't know how the script to implement this, Thank you for your help.